Do I need an index for a frequently updated column
I have a table T with an integer column C. It's very unlikely that number of T rows will exceed 1000. The system is loaded with real-time queries of two types (each with a same frequency):

Search for a T row with lowest C and increment it by N.
Search for a T row by primary key and decrement it back by N.

Should I use an index for for T.C?

Most likely Yes. Check your query plans, using explain(analyze,  verbose, buffers, settings). And if you need help, please share these plans, in plain text, and the DDL for all tables and indexes involved.

Time complexity of a sequential scan is always worse O(n) than an index scan O(log n),  where n is the number of elements.

However inserting operation (but not deletion because in PostgreSQL is performed logically, until the VACUUM process is carried out) slows down in direct proportion to the number of indexes. For update case, depends on what columns are updated, for all columns it behaves as the insert case.

Probably not. Use EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) to analyze the performance of your actual statements, with and without the index.

In small tables, indexes are not that useful as with big tables. With 1000 rows or less, the gain an index provides could be marginal.
